# Duplicating topology over a mesh to save time (duplicating topology for fingers)

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap, retopology

I have a hand which I am trying to retopologise.

[image]

And I would like to duplicate the topology on the index finger over to the middle figure.

[image]

But I need to be able to 'tweak' the topology since the size of the index and middle finger are different. Is there a way to 'pinch' the duplicated topology to fit nicely around the middle finger so I can shrinkwrap it nicely?

I have attached the blender file below if you'd like to have a go.

[image]